# Is it possible to change the default placeholder value of file type input using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am facing one issue. Is this possible to change the file type input default text `i.e-No file choosen` and set the custom placeholder value. Actually i need to set the custom placeholder value inside the file type input. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></span>
            <input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload" id="bannerimage"  ng-model="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-select="onFileSelect($file);">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I need to change that default text `No file choosen` to `Add driving Licence`.

Comment: You have missed an important detail that, you have used [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Comment: You can not change it. It is a property which browser holds.

Comment: You can rather have custom design hiding the default `input`  and writing events to trigger the functionality of input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the default labels `No file choosen` on buttons, they are hard-coded in browsers

Using label you can assign custom text, hide the input element and add label for file input element,

```
<input type="file" id="file" class="filestyle form-control hidden" data-size="lg" name="upload" id="bannerimage"  ng-model="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-select="onFileSelect($file);" >
<label for="file">{{fileInputPlaceHolder}}</label>
```

Comment: I did as per you but its not working . Please check this [plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/R1xLGpiHkTXZNHC9mxwo?p=preview).

Comment: @subhra please check https://plnkr.co/edit/c0VeIIUfGeiapW2Z4vYU?p=preview

Comment: I dont want to hide that input text field because I will show there the added file path/fakepath.

Comment: check this updated https://plnkr.co/edit/c0VeIIUfGeiapW2Z4vYU?p=preview

Comment: Here I need when user will click on that button the file explorer will open and path will display on that text box still your latest plunkr need some modification.

Comment: Please Check now

Comment: @subhra Welcome :)